# Having to repeat JS block for multiple locations how can I create a more practical method

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I am creating kind of a dual navigation menu/map functionality where you can click on certain locations and a new panel will display, hiding the previously viewed panel. Also with a map hover effect. Here is what I'm working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ez6dv90/).

I'm trying to figure out a best method to shorten my functions as there would be multiple locations. The block below is what I'm repeating over and over again for new locations. It covers the click and hover on the map. I know repeating the block below isn't practical so I'm hoping someone can guide me.

```
$('a#united-states').click(function(event){
    $('.list').removeClass('current');
    $('div.united-states').addClass('current');                        
    event.preventDefault();
})
$('span.us').mouseover(function(){
   $('.list').removeClass('current');
   $('div.united-states').addClass('current');
}).mouseout(function(){
   $('div.united-states').removeClass('current');
   $('.list').addClass('current');
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel list current">
        <ul class="locations">
          <li><a href="#" id="united-states">United States</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#" id="canada">Canada</a></li>  
          <li><a href="#" id="africa">Africa</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="panel united-states">
        <h3>United States of America</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec quam tristique, ullamcorper dolor at, facilisis dui. Sed faucibus eros vel purus finibus congue. Phasellus non ante laoreet, faucibus metus vel, accumsan massa. Sed tincidunt eros sed purus interdum, id vehicula elit rhoncus. </p>
        <p><a href="#" id="list">Back to list</a></p>
    </div><!--/.panel-->
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ez6dv90/) link should give a better idea. If there is not better method, just let me know I'm more than happy to just live with this :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the region/country `a` elements a common class, say `region` and all the `span` elements a common class, say `pin`. Then for each `a` or `span` element replace the id with or add a `data-attribute` matching the region/country. Now, it won't matter how many regions you add, as long as you stick to these simple rules, the following code should work for all the regions/countries:

```
$('.region').click(function(event){
    $('.list').removeClass('current');
    var region = $(this).data('region');
    $('div.' + region).addClass('current');                        
    event.preventDefault();
});
$('.map > .pin').mouseover(function(){
    $('.list,.panel').removeClass('current');
    var region = $(this).data('region');
    $('div.' + region).addClass('current');
}).mouseout(function(){
    var region = $(this).data('region');
    $('div.' + region).removeClass('current');
    $('.list').addClass('current');
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/4ez6dv90/6/)

**EDIT 1:**

For the back link to work -- do the following. Change:

```
<p><a href="#" id="list">Back to list</a></p>
```

To:

```
<p><a href="#" class="back-list">Back to list</a></p>
```

Then add the following code:

```
$('.back-list').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.panel').removeClass('current');
    $('.list').addClass('current');
});
```

You do not want to use duplicate IDs, every ID must be unique. In fact, you may not even need IDs.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/4ez6dv90/7/)

Comment: Sweet. I completely forgot about the back link, thanks so much! Both yours and @CAllen work. You have provided a thorough explanation which helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id attribute. For example:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    var loc = this.id; // united-states | canada | africa

    if( loc == 'list' ) {
        $('.panel').removeClass('current');
        $('.list').addClass('current');
        return;
    }

    $('.list').removeClass('current');
    $('div.' + loc).addClass('current');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and as for the mouse over, you can grab the class attribute and change class 'us' to 'united-states' to be consistent in:

```
<div class="map">
    <!-- changed class to 'united-states' -->
    <span class="united-states"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-location-128.png" alt="US location" /></span>
    <!-- changed end -->
</div>

$('span').mouseover(function(){
    var loc = $( this ).attr( 'class' ); // us | canada | africa
    $('.list').removeClass('current');
    $('div.' + loc).addClass('current');
}).mouseout(function(){
    var loc = $( this ).attr( 'class' ); // us | canada | africa
    $('div.' + loc).removeClass('current');
    $('.list').addClass('current');
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure if I was clear with what I was looking to do. I wanted to take all the links that list the countries and somehow when clicked on show the relevant content panel for it (perhaps there's a better method in rewriting my script), rather than creating another block for lets say Europe and South America. I hope I'm explaning it correctly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Your code helped out too. Wish I could upvote yours and @PeterKA but it won't let me as I'm new here.

Comment: Its ok...We are all here to help